# Automatic queue creation in activemq

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, activemq-classic, spring-jms

In my application, if any client signups, I create a dedicated queue for him( currently manually, clients are enterprise clients, so not many) by adding bean in xml file and then restarting the application. Whenever clients call my rest api to submit message, I add it to the their queue and appropriate jms receiver is called. I am not sure whether queues could be created using a rest api (I am using spring mvc) and  this is queue remains permanently in my xml file.
I have tried going through various sources but couldn't find anything which is related to mine.

Can somebody suggest what is the "correct way" of implementing this?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure you can create producers of messages to queues and topics and consumers of them dynamically with Java. Just look at the examples in the documentation:

[ActiveMQ Hello World example](http://activemq.apache.org/version-5-hello-world.html)